# How to align if-condition in equation systems

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I use this environment for an equation system:

```
\newenvironment{sistema}{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}{\end{array}\right.}
```

But in this way the "if-conditions" are not aligned, as an example:

```
\[
\lvert a \rvert =
\begin{sistema}
a \quad \text{if } a > 0 \\
-a  \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{sistema}
\]
```

Is it possible to align them? (Or even simpler) is there any other enviroment that build sytems automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

...

\[
\lvert a \rvert =
\begin{cases}
a  & \text{if $a>0$,} \\
-a & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\]
```

You probably found the `sistema` environment on the [GuIT forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/index.php?option=com_kunena&view=listcat&catid=0&lang=it&func=listcat&Itemid=72), but that's for single equations. The more general `cases` environment is just for this kind of applications.

Notice that putting a formula inside `\text` avoids cumbersome uses of spaces.

Comment: Yes, more precisely I've found it in the [Pantieri's website](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX.html). Anyway `cases` is perfect. Grazie.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `cases`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\lvert a \rvert =
\begin{cases}
a & \text{if } a > 0 \\
-a & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Or you could use the more adaptable tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\lvert a \rvert =
\left\lbrace
\begin{tabular}{rl}
a & \text{if } a > 0 \\
-a & \text{otherwise}
\end{tabular}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that this environment allows you an arbitrary number of "columns" separated by `&` symbols and you can specify how each is to be aligned. In this case the first is right aligned so the "`a`"s match up, the second left aligned so the case conditions line up.

Comment: Yes, `cases` is what I'm looking for. Thanks.